# в java swing не получается добавить меню

Tags: java, swing

пишу змейку на джаве, написал её всю в jpanel, теперь хочу добавить кнопку меню "Файл"->"Новая игра",
но само меню не появляется.
Вот класс main

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
}}
```

теперь в MainWindow создаю меню и ставлю setVisible( true)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public MainWindow() {
        setSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("New");
        mb.add(menu);  
        setJMenuBar(mb);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Но меню не появляется, только голое окно, почему?

Comment: Нужно добавит  JMenu  в JMenuBar

Comment: уже добавлял, если туда добавить кнопку```JButton button = new JButton(); 
add(button) ```она появится,  а меню ни в какую

Comment: Исправленный пример у меня работает (появляется строка меню с пунктом New), версия JRE 1.8.0_261